# makefile error lib/Scrt1.o undefined reference to `main'

Tags: c++, makefile

I glanced tons of similar topic, but I couldn't recognize solution

I tried mine and many variations. Even below the simplest code compiling doesn't work. I think skipping little thing...
Could you help me?

```
    # Make file for test.c file dependencies external C libraries

    CC = g++
    C = gcc
    FLAGS = -Wextra -g
    INCLUDES = -lm

test: randomArray.o test.o
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) randomArray.o -o test 

test.o: randomArray.o
    $(C) $(FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c test.cpp  

randomArray.o: randomArray.c
    $(C) $(FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c randomArray.c
```

Error message

```
make
g++ -Wextra -g -lm randomArray.o -o test 
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/10.2.0/../../../../lib/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:9: test] Error 1
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "randomArray.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int *bit=randomArray(64);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
    {
        
        cout<<bit[i]<< "\n";
    }
    
    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `Makefile` rule `test.o: randomArray.o` should probably be `test.o: test.cpp`. The variable `INCLUDES = -lm` is misleading as `-lm` specifies a library for linking. In `INCLUDES` I would expect a specification of include directories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to link in `test.o`:

```
test: randomArray.o test.o
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) randomArray.o test.o -o test
```

Also note that `test.o: randomArray.o` is probably wrong. It says `test.o` depends on `randomArray.o`, which it doesn't. It depends on `test.cpp`.

```
test.o: test.cpp
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c test.cpp
```